# Calendar Overlay Workflow

Tags: sharepoint-server, workflow

I have a master corporate calendar that I would like to color code with other events (holidays, other business events, etc). Is it possible to create a workflow so that my overlay calendars automatically populate in the master calendar? This master calendar is the one we use to connect with outlook. I want it color coded with all the overlays but I dont want to share all the overlays.

Comment: I'm not completely sure, but I thought overlayed calendars don't show on outlook. It's just the events from the calendar directly connected, and not the overlayed calendars that show.

Answer (score 0):

Per my knowledge, it will be hard for you to use workflow to do this. You may need to change your goal to see if there is a workaround.